# Docker: Sandbox-Proxy crashes immediately (HDP 3.0.1)

Tags: docker, ubuntu-server

So I recently installed Ubuntu Server and Docker on my system.
Then I downloaded the most recent deploy-scripts from hortonworks.

I ran those and now have two docker containers installed.
While "sandbox-hdp" starts without problems, the "sandbox-proxy" stopps immediately.

When using: "docker logs sandbox-proxy" it outputs:

> [emerg] 1#1: host not found in upstream "sandbox-hdp" in /etc/nginx/conf.d/http-hdp.conf:9

I've tried different things, but none of them did change my logs output.

I suspect that it refers to port-mapping-issues but currently have no clue how to solve this.

Is there any way to get more information?

Thanks for your support.

regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in Ubuntu terminal

```
sudo bash docker-deploy-hdp30.sh
```

Or even better use with screen (because it will take ~20 min)

```
screen -dmS hdp bash -c 'sudo bash docker-deploy-hdp30.sh'
```

More about it: https://medium.com/@tomas_savenas/hortonworks-sandbox-hdp-3-0-on-ubuntu-18-04-using-docker-da579fd654f9

Comment: Thanks for your effort. In the end I used the VirtualBox VM to test the sandbox. Since I deleted the docker container I can't say whether it would have worked or not.

Answer (score 1):

Could you please provide the output for executing the docker-deploy-hdpX.sh script?

I had the same problem, and in my case the shell that I am using does not recognize '==' for string equality and hence the 'hostname' variable is not set. This is resulting in a null string being passed to the 'network-alias' and -h (hostname) option in docker run command and hence the issue (sandbox-hdp seemingly starts without problems, but actually with wrong hostname).

To fix the problem, I just replaced '==' with '=' in the following if condition code.

```
# start the docker container and proxy

if [ "$flavor" = "hdf" ]; then

hostname="sandbox-hdf.hortonworks.com"

elif [ "$flavor" = "hdp" ]; then

hostname="sandbox-hdp.hortonworks.com"

fi
```

Comment: Thanks for your effort. In the end I used the VirtualBox VM to test the sandbox. Since I deleted the docker container I can't say whether it would have worked or not.